# Problem with H-bridge driving a small motor

Tags: h-bridge

I am asking this question because I am literally out of ideas with what might be wrong with my small circuit. It's essentially a 2-channel bipolar H-bridge, that drives two small motors.

H-brige: [TB6674PG](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/DST_TB6674-TDE_EN_21350-472708.pdf) 
Motor: [PNN7RE08JD](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NMB-MAT/PNN7.pdf)

I have wired the H-bridge like so:
[image]

where `IN A` and `IN B` are TTL inputs, corresponding to clockwise or counter-clockwise rotation of the motor. I have no resistors between the outputs of the H bridge and the motor.

I have not connected `VS1B` to anything (but see later). When the circuit is powered, `VS1B` shows a voltage of 11.4 V.

**Problem**:

The `B` channel does work. I can make the motor turn either direction as I change the TTL level. The voltage on `VS1A` is always 12 V, and the one on `VS1B` (which I have not connected to anything) is 8.4 V. 
 (This is not a typo: `VS1A` has the power, and `VS1B` has nothing, but the `B` channel works and the `A` channel does not).

However, the `A` channel does **not** work! 
 This has happened with multiple H-bridges of the same type now, and it's always channel `B` that works. My box actually has 4 channels so two H-bridges each, and on the second one I see the same behaviour. Which makes me think it's not just a broken component but something systematic.

What I have tried:

- I have tried to give a load to both channels `A` and `B`: `B` works, `A` does not.
- I have connected `VS1B` to 12 V as well. When that happens, **none** of the two channels work.

---

Is there anything blatantly wrong that I am doing?

Comment: the IC is supposed to drive one stepping motor

Comment: where does it say on the data sheet? Why would they have two channels then?

Comment: it says that in the first few words on the first page ... why two channels? research how stepping motors work

Comment: Why did you leave VS1B unpowered?  Powering that is most definitely required!  You may have damaged the IC via lossy internal paths when not properly powered.  While its *probably* that you can use this for a brushed DC motor instead of the intended stepper motor, it's also quite unclear how you came to be trying to do so.  What lead you to believe this was a good idea?

Comment: Because I am an idiot.

Comment: Which answers both comments.

Comment: @SuperCiocia someone learning and working hard cannot be idiot. All these mistakes and seemingly lost time are part of the learning process.

Comment: Happy to accept an answer if the comments are made into one.